HikariCP Connection Pool Exhaustion with Testcontainers and Spring Boot when Building with Gradle
I am using Testcontainers with Spring Boot for integration testing in my project, but I'm facing an issue where the HikariCP connection pool becomes exhausted, leading to Connection is not available, request timed out errors. This issue only occurs when I build and run tests using Gradle. When I build and run the same tests in IntelliJ IDEA, everything works fine.
My Setup:
Spring Boot version: 3.2.5
Testcontainers version: 1.19.7
Database: MySQL 8.0.37 (using the official MySQL Docker image)
JPA provider: Hibernate
Connection pool: HikariCP
Build tool: Gradle (issue only occurs here)
Problem:
During test execution with Gradle, I frequently encounter the following error:
Caused by: java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-2 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30003ms.
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createTimeoutException(HikariPool.java:696)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:181)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:146)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:128)
    ...


The slice tests (MemberRepositoryTest, PartnersRepositoryTest) that directly access the database are failing.
Other repository tests (Item, Brand, Cart) are succeeding without issues.
The failing tests run successfully when executed individually.
A database connection error occurs: CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction.
This is followed by a HikariCP connection pool timeout error: JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection [HikariPool-2 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30006ms], indicating that the database connections are exhausted. Because of this, JPA cannot establish a connection and thus cannot start a transaction.
Occasionally, the PartnersRepositoryTest passes, but this is inconsistent.
The SQL logs also show frequent table drops and recreations, which might be contributing to the issue, but I’m not sure how to handle this or if it is related.

Below is the code for 'MemberRepositoryTest
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
@ImportTestcontainers(InitializeTestContainers.class)
public class MemberRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    MemberRepository memberRepository;

    @Nested
    class Create {
        @Test
        void createMember() {
            ....
        }
    }

    @Nested
    class Find {
        @Test
        void findMember() {
            ....
        }

        @Test
        void optionalEmpty_MemberNotFound() {
            ....
        }
    }
}

What I've Tried:

Increasing the maximumPoolSize to allow more connections, but the issue persists when building with Gradle.
Setting leakDetectionThreshold to detect connection leaks, but no leaks are reported in the logs.
Adjusting parallel test execution settings in JUnit to control the number of tests running simultaneously.
Redefined DB connection settings in the test yml configuration: All relevant settings are confirmed within the yml file, ruling out environment variable issues.
Removed TestContainer and switched to @SpringBootTest
Unified JVM settings between Gradle and IntelliJ:

Questions:

What could be causing HikariCP to exhaust connections specifically when building with Gradle?
How can I better configure HikariCP or Testcontainers to avoid this issue with Gradle builds?
Could the frequent table drops and recreations be related to the connection pool exhaustion, and how should I address this in my testing setup?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

HikariPool-2... - what is the maximum number have you seen in logs?

I've seen up to HikariPool-4 in the logs.
